# max temperature for every month given several months and several years

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if this is the right place to put this.

So I have a dataframe consisting of just 4 columns but around 2000 rows.
It's in a csv format. A typical value of the first column which is titled month actually looks like so: 1;1990-01-02;1990;1;23
So it seems that 1 is the index, then we have the year, month, and day. The two other numbers don't make sense and I think I can throw them out. I want to clean up this column and put it into some date format because the 4th column contains precipitation information (with many NaN's)that I want to look into. I'd like to get the maximum temperature over every month.

Here's what I started out by doing

[image]

I then want to just get the 1st index of that list by doing

```
df["MONTH"]=df["MONTH"].map(lambda x: x[1])
```

but I get an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The next step would have been to do something like

```
df["MONTH"]=pd.to_datetime[df["MONTH"]]
```

How do I fix my error (or is there a better way of doing it?) and then get the max PRCP for January of 1990, February of 1990, ..., November of 2020 (some dates of some months are missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I fix my error?

The error comes from trying to map `x.split(';')` again *after* the `MONTH` strings had already been mapped into lists. You can only run that line once. Also note that index 1 can be accessed immediately like `x.split(';')[1]` instead of mapping `x.split(';')` and then mapping `x[1]`.

> Or is there a better way of doing it?

**Yes, it's best to use the vectorized [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) methods** instead of `Series.map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MONTH': ['1;1990-01-02;1990;1;23', '2;1990-01-04;1990;1;23', '3;1990-01-05;1990;1;25', '4;1990-02-02;1990;2;23', '5;1990-02-04;1990;2;23'], 'PRCP': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 9, 5]})

#                     MONTH  PRCP
# 0  1;1990-01-02;1990;1;23   NaN
# 1  2;1990-01-04;1990;1;23   NaN
# 2  3;1990-01-05;1990;1;25   3.0
# 3  4;1990-02-02;1990;2;23   9.0
# 4  5;1990-02-04;1990;2;23   5.0
```

```
df['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MONTH'].str.split(';').str[1])

#        MONTH  PRCP
# 0 1990-01-02   NaN
# 1 1990-01-04   NaN
# 2 1990-01-05   3.0
# 3 1990-02-02   9.0
# 4 1990-02-04   5.0
```

> How do I get the max `PRCP` for January of 1990, February of 1990, ..., November of 2020?

Use [`Series.groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) to compute the max `PRCP` per year-month:

- Either group by `Month of YYYY` strings using [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

  ```
  ym = df.MONTH.dt.strftime('%B of %Y')
  df.groupby(ym).PRCP.max()

  # MONTH
  # February of 1990    9.0
  # January of 1990     3.0
  # Name: PRCP, dtype: float64
  ```
- Or group by explicit years and months using [`Series.dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`Series.dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

  ```
  ym = [df['MONTH'].dt.year, df['MONTH'].dt.month]
  df.groupby(ym)['PRCP'].max()

  # MONTH  MONTH
  # 1990   1        3.0
  #        2        9.0
  # Name: PRCP, dtype: float64
  ```

Comment: wow. that's very neat. thank you